# Getting chained Promise response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm having some problems getting a response from a chained Promise.

I have my component where the chain starts

**component**

```
  componentDidMount = async ()=> {
    try{
      const products = await post('payments/getProducts', {});
      console.log(products);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
```

This component calls my API helper:

```
async function post(url, data) { 
token = null;  
if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
  token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
} 
    try {
      const response = axios({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${token}`,
        },
        data,
        url: `${API_URL}${url}`,
      })
      return response;
    } catch(e){
      Promise.reject(e);
    }
  }
```

and my API Helper then calls a Firebase Cloud Function which calls Stripe:

```
paymentRouter.post('/getProducts', (req, res) => {
  return stripe.products.list()
  .then(products => {
    console.log(products.data)
    return products.data;
  })
  .catch(e => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', err.message, e);
  })
})
```

Calling the function is no problem, and my Cloud Function logs out the product data, but I can't get the response to log in my API Helper nor my component.

Comment: First thing I see you are not using `await` in your helper before `axios`.

Comment: Thanks, missed that one.  Added it in but no joy yet

Comment: `post` is a mistake. It's `async` but you're doing nothing it could help with. There should be no try..catch - you're catching an error later. Also, you're not returning `Promise.reject(e)`. This way you suppress an error. Just remove `async` and return `axios(...)` from that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Promise.reject(e);
```

That is completely senseless as it creates a new rejected promise that is not used anywhere. You could `await` it so that it gets chained into the promise returned by the `async function`, or you just return the promise from axios:

```
async function post(url, data) {    
  let token = null; // always declare variables!
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
  } 

  return axios({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `${token}`,
    },
    data,
    url: `${API_URL}${url}`,
  });
}
```

Now the errors don't go into nowhere anymore and you can probably debug the problem :)

Comment: Thanks, something is still not right. After a delay, I can see `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <firebase url> with MIME type application/json`  Although I've had enough of these errors to suspect its a red herring